# SQL count query based on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a **count** query in mysql to update a column (`no_of_orders`) in my `users` table using data from another table (`orders`).

The table I want to perform a query on is the `orders` table that has a `created_date` column in **datetime** format.

I would like to count the number of orders each user has made in the last 3 months.

I have tried the below and I am getting an error "Operand should only contain one column".

```
UPDATE users u SET no_of_orders = (
SELECT EXTRACT(month from created_date)>= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ,
COUNT(*)
FROM orders o
WHERE o.created_by = u.user_id);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to look into `GROUP BY`. That won't solve your problem, but may help.

Comment: The update is not correct. Move the extract part in the where clause and put same sub-query outside with ```where exists``` clause too.

Comment: The error comes from the select clause, you select 2 data and the update expect only 1 data. You should separate the count and extract.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT` join the table `users` to a query that aggregates in the table `orders`:

```
UPDATE users u 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) count
  FROM orders
  WHERE created_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
  GROUP BY created_by
) o ON o.created_by = u.user_id 
SET u.no_of_orders = COALESCE(o.count, 0);
```

Comment: hi, thank you but this returns the total number of orders, not ones made in the last 3 months

Comment: @lavender1 dis you miss `WHERE created_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH` ?

Comment: No, I copied your answer exactly

Comment: @lavender1 then either you are doing something wrong or `created_date` is not a valid datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users u SET no_of_orders = (
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM orders o
WHERE o.created_by = u.user_id AND  EXTRACT(month from o.created_date)>= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) GROUP BY o.created_by;
```

In sub-query you are returning more than one column that's why the error